# Python, django sessions, how update django session by key

Tags: python, django

i try to update my session data

my code:

```
    try:
        s = Session.objects.get(session_key=token)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        return 400, {"error": "Token invalid."}

    newObject = {'user_pk': 3, 'company_id': 55}
    s['user_login_info'] = newObject
    s.save()
```

but i get error
`TypeError: 'Session' object does not support item assignment`

how correctly update session data?

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the source below.

> The key point is that session_data is a pickled dictionary. The
> Session Middleware takes care of deserializing and serializing as a
> convenience, but since you're not using it, you'll have to do the
> extra bits yourself.

```
d = s.get_decoded()
d['user_login_info'] = newObject
s.session_data = d
s.save()
```

[Source](https://groups.google.com/g/django-users/c/fncup-Q6h7k)

Answer (score 0):

this modification of first answer should update session data:

```
d= s.get_decoded()
d['user_login_info'] = newObject
s.session_data = SessionStore().encode(d)
s.save()
```